# Applicant/inventor address change right before PCT national phase entry

Tags: patent-applications, pct, wipo, national-stage, address

I have filed a PCT application with International Bureau of WIPO almost 30 months ago. Now I want to enter the national phase in the US, the UK and Canada. I am the sole inventor/applicant and I'm not living at the address I provided to WIPO during filing the International application anymore. In other words, now I am living at an address different from the inventor/applicant address on my published WIPO application. When filing national phase applications can I simply enter my new address as my mailing/residential address, or the address I provide to national office during national phase application should necessarily be the same as the address on my published WIPO application?
Considering that I only have 4 days left until the 30 months deadline of the national phase entry, is it OK to submit my address change request to IB under Rule92bis now? I'm afraid that the change might not be recorded and the form PCT/IB/306 might not be issued in the remaining 4 days.